# Router navigation failed, and no previous location could be restored

Tags: aurelia

It seems that when Aurelia encounter a problem when "compiling" views we cannot get precisely error's stack trace but just an error relative to it's consequence (Can't load view ...)

To try it, write a wrong binding like this, or use a wrong value converter:
... repeat.for="elt in list" ...

And you will get, if this is your first view:

"Router navigation failed, and no previous location could be restored"

How to get real stack trace, this lack of error management is very, very time consuming.

NB: Aurelia main.js is setup like this:

```
aurelia.use
   .standardConfiguration()
   .developmentLogging();
```

Comment: Please open an issue in the Aurelia `templating` or `routing` github repositories and we'll see what we can do to improve this.